# How can I make OSX accept positional arguments before options?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I recently switched from Linux to OSX. I use console heavily, and previously I was able to do things like

```
ls ./dir -sgh
cp ./file ./dir -Rf
```

and so on. If I missed an option, it was enough to press <kbd>up</kbd> and just add it. OSX forces me to put options before arguments, like this:

```
ls -sgh ./dir
cp -Rf ./file ./dir
```

This behavior is frustrating, it is easy to forget about an option and you have to navigate to the beggining of a line just to add it. It is also hard to add another option if you forget about one.

Is there an easy way to fix this behavior and make it work the linux way? I guess it involves replacing default programs like `ls` with some counterparts.

Comment: This is handled by whatever library the commands use to process command-line arguments. It's not something you can configure.

Comment: I realize I cannot fix it by clicking on some checkbox. I just wonder if I can do anything.

Comment: Ideally? Retrain your habits to work with tools that conform strictly with the POSIX standard -- then you'll have habits that work everywhere, rather than (in this case) only on GNU. Perpetuating the crutch means perpetuating your need for the crutch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X's userland is a mash of BSD, (outdated) GNU, and Apple utilities.
If want your utilities to behave like their Linux counterparts, you should probably install the entire GNU coreutils suite with something like
[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Once Homebrew is installed, just use it to install the coreutils:

```
$ brew install coreutils
```

Edit: I didn't have to update my `$PATH` personally, but YMMV.

If your shell isn't finding the Homebrew-installed coreutils, make sure `/usr/local/bin` (or your custom path, if Homebrew was configured as such) is before `/usr/bin` and `/bin` on `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

In the best-case scenario, all programs dynamically link the system `libc` and use `getopt` to process their arguments. `getopt` only looks at arguments until it finds the first non-option argument, then stops. You cannot change this behavior of `getopt`. You would have to replace the system `libc` with one having a different implementation of `getopt`.

However, there is no guaranteed that all programs load `libc` dynamically; some might link statically, in which case replacing the system `libc` would have no effect. Others may not even use `getopt`. In either case, the only option is to replace the program with one that behaves the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Option processing is not a feature of the shell. You'd need to patch the argument processing logic in each individual utility.

Alternatively, you could install e.g. the corresponding GNU utilities. They are not completely option-compatible with the default *BSD utilities, so you can't replace the system binaries; but you can  arrange your `PATH` so that the locally installed versions are preferred for your personal use. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is popular  for managing this.

In Bash, ctrl-A jumps to the beginning of line, and M-n jumps past the first token.

Comment: I realize it's not a shell feature. I just wonder if there is something I can do to make it work differently. I realize the solution probably involves replacing existing `ls`, `cp`, etc binaries with other ones.

Comment: See update just now.